# css Star-rating html

Tags: html, css

Im following a tutorial on this page:
http://www.henryhoffman.com/css-star-rating-tutorial.html where the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="rating">
<li><a href="#" title="1 Star">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="2 Stars">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="3 Stars">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="4 Stars">4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="5 Stars">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
ul.rating{
background:url(../img/site_img/star.jpg) bottom;
height:21px;
width:115px;
overflow:hidden;
}

ul.rating li{
display:inline
}
.rating a {
display:block;
width:23px;
height:21px;
float:left;
text-indent:-9999px;
position:relative;
}
.rating a:hover {
background:url(../img/site_img/star.jpg) center;
width:115px;
margin-left:-92px;
position:static;
}
.rating a:active {
background-position:top;
}
```

My problem is that I dont want an a href, I don't want to be transferd to another possition on the page. I just want the the value (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5) to be stored in a label so I can pass that value to the database when I press a button. And if I choose three stars I want three stars to be colured after a pressed the stars and dont hoover the stars anymore.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just change your `a hrefs` into spans, seeing as the CSS already declared a `display:block` this should work. Also in CSS change `rating a` to `rating span` See if that helps.

```
<ul class="rating">
<li><span>1</span></li>...

.rating span {
display:block;...
```

Comment: Yes, that works, I dont get transferd. I'm going to try and see how I can save the Span value and how I can make the selection to be colured even if I dont hover the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

This i similar, should get you on the right track. There are a couple of functions I do not include here, however the base is there for you to work with.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n76My/5/

```
var index=1;
$(".beeRating li").on({
mouseover: function() {
    if(index==1)
    {
      $(this).addClass('stop');
      $("li").each(function(index,domEle) {
      $(domEle).css('opacity', '1');
      if( $(this).hasClass('stop') ) {
        return false;
    }
})
}
},

 mouseleave: function() {
 if(index==1)
{
$(this).removeClass('stop');
$("li").each(function(index,domEle) {
    $(domEle).css('opacity', '.25');
})
}
},
click: function() {
var rating = $(this).attr('id');
console.log(rating);
index=0;
$.ajax({    // do ajax request
   url: "/echo/json/"

   }).done(function() {
      alert("success");
      index=1;  // on done set the index as 1
    });
   }
});
```