# How can I create a star based feedback system for a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm creating a website for fun, one of the pages is a feedback page. On here I have many containers, inside each other and with different things in them. I wanted to  create a star-based feedback rating, I have two images, one is an empty star and the other is a filled star. On first look the star is empty and I want it to change to the filled star, which I have done! Now, when trying to change multiple images, I can't seem to find a way to do it. For example, is someone is leaving a four star rating, I want the all the stars to the left and including the clicked star to change to the other image.

Here is my HTML for the images:

```
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="1" onclick="change();">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="2" onclick="change();">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="3" onclick="change();">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="4" onclick="change();">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="5" onclick="change();">
```

And here is my JavaScript to change one image only:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
    var image1 = document.getElementById('1');
    image1.src = "filledStar.png";
}
```

So if I click on the fifth image I want all of the images to change, and if I click on the fourth most right image I want that image and all of the images to the left to change etc etc.

Comment: http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating/demo

Comment: This has been done so many times, that you should be able to find any number of plugins/snippets which do it that you can dissect to learn the implmentation of such a feature. eg [jQuery plugin](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty) [Angular directive](http://codepen.io/TepigMC/pen/FIdHb) [knockout bindingHandler](https://rateit.codeplex.com/discussions/452084) pick your favourite library!

Comment: possible duplicate of [css Star-rating html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921157/css-star-rating-html)

Comment: http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

In your HTML page, pass arrays containing strings to the Javascript change() function based on which stars should be changed. For example:

```
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="1" onclick="change(['1']);">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="2" onclick="change(['1', '2']);">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="3" onclick="change(['1', '2', '3']);">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="4" onclick="change(['1', '2', '3', '4']);">
<img src="star.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="5" onclick="change(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']);">
```

Then, in Javscript, accept the array as an argument in 'change()', and iterate over it. For each item (each 'id' of a star that must be changed),  get the element from the page using the 'id' from the array, and set its src attribute to the new image, just like you've already done.

Good luck!